# Derivation of the Euler characteristics of the moduli space of rational curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, moduli-space

I am looking for references / hints of proof on the derivation of the Euler characteristics $\chi(\mathcal M_{0,n})=(-1)^{n-1} (n-3)!$ of the moduli space of rational $n$-pointed curves.

I have been trying to show this by using recursion and gluing rules on boundary divisors, but 
(i) I have to apply a bizarre selection rule for the boundary divisors, 
(ii) I am wondering if I am not making a conceptual mistake by mixing up $\mathcal M_{0,n}$ and its Deligne-Mumford compactification.

Comment: Are you looking at $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{0,n}$ or $\mathcal{M}_{0,n}$? The latter doesn't have boundary divisors, as it is the moduli space of smooth curves...

Comment: So yeah, it sounds like you may be mixing up the two of them.

Comment: Also, you appear to be off by a sign: $\mathcal{M}_{0,3} = {pt}$, which has Euler characteristic 1. But your sign suggests it should be -1.

Comment: You are right, sign corrected. Concerning $\mathcal M_{0,n}$ or $\overline{\mathcal M}_{0,n}$; is the Euler characteristics of the latter known in full generality ?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. The argument I provide doesn't obviously seem like it should extend, since the Euler characteristic is no longer constant on fibres of the forgetful maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a sketch, and probably needs a little detail-filling in.

For the sake of laziness, I'm going to write $M_{0,n}$ instead of $\mathcal{M}_{0,n}$.

You can think of $M_{0,n}$ as the space of punctured curves. Moreover, you have natural forgetful maps
$$
M_{0,n+1} \to M_{0,n}
$$
given by forgetting points. What is the fibre of such a map? Well, it is just the (punctured) curve itself! Consequently, its Euler characteristic can be computed to be $\chi(C,x_1, \ldots, x_{n+1}) = (2 - (n+1))$.

So playing around with the fact that Euler characteristics on fibrations are multiplicative...

Anyhow, this isn't rigorous, but it should give you an outline to work with.